# Magento system.xml groups multiselect

Tags: php, magento

In admin panel menu->configurate I'm have a tab.
I'm using:

```
<frontend_type>Multiselect</frontend_type>  
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_customer_group_multiselect</source_model>
```

and I get a three users group, namely a GENERAL, RETAIL, WHOLESELER.

Question, how to get fourth group, namely a NOT LOGGED IN?

Comment: NOT LOGGED IN is treated a little different, for example you cannot create customers in that group, so this source model is not returning it.

Comment: I dosen't need create customers in this group, I need get in multiselect a NOT lOGGED IN with others group

Comment: The point is, the source model you are using is used in the customer creation tab, where the NOT LOGGED IN group is not needed, so this source model is not including that group. I am not aware of other source models which have it, you either have to create your own or add that group manually.

Comment: Thanks, but did you know how to add that group manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling core model you can define your own observer in system.xml

Please find below code which will solve your problem.

```
 <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_GroupCollection</source_model>
```

Now create your GroupCollection.php file in your local\community (working directory) in below path.

```
e.g app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Model\System\Config\Source\GroupCollection.php
```

Add below code in that file.

```
<?php
class Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_GroupCollection
{
 /**
     * Options getter
     *
     * @return array
     */
     public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getCollection();
        $groupArray = array();
        foreach ($group as $eachGroup) {
        $groupData = array(
                    'customer_group_id' => $eachGroup->getCustomerGroupId(),
                    'customer_group_code' => $eachGroup->getCustomerGroupCode(),
                     'tax_class_id' => $eachGroup->getTaxClassId() // we dont required this
                    );
        if (!empty($groupData)) {
            array_push($groupArray, $groupData);
        }
       }
          var_dump($groupArray);
    }
}
```

Following will be your output.

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'customer_group_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      'customer_group_code' => string 'NOT LOGGED IN' (length=13)
      'tax_class_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'customer_group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'customer_group_code' => string 'General' (length=7)
      'tax_class_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'customer_group_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'customer_group_code' => string 'Wholesale' (length=9)
      'tax_class_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'customer_group_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'customer_group_code' => string 'Retailer' (length=8)
      'tax_class_id' => string '3' (length=1)
```

And you are done! :)

Comment: Thanks, I try do what you say and it work, but that not exactly what I need and I rewrite core module like this,

 public function toOptionArray()
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')
                ->loadData()->toOptionArray();
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }

just deleted this:

->setRealGroupsFilter()

from code

Comment: Without you I would not have thought of it!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need create 'Mage' catalog in 'local' or rewrite core module! If you will look into **`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Customer/Group/Multiselect.php`**, you will see that this class doesn't extend nothing! So, you can create in yours folder **`NameSpace/ModuleName/Model`** your own **`Exemple.php`** and just copy ***all*** from Multiselect.php to **Exemple.php**, fix there what do you want(in your case just delete *`->setRealGroupsFilter()`* string), and set your model in system.xml.
For exemple, if in your config.xml you have

```
<models>
    <my_model>
        <class>NameSpace_ModuleName_Model</class>
    </my_model>
</models>
```

than you have to write

```
<source_model>my_model/exemple</source_model>
```

in your system.xml!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use the Magento source customer group:

```
<field id="customer_group" type="multiselect">
   <label>Customer Groups</label>
   <source_model>Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Source\Group</source_model>
</field>
```